# File name and sheet name from Excel macro

Tags: c#, .net, excel, vba

I have recorded a macro with few excel operations i performed in two different excel files . After that i saved the macro file (.xlsm). Through c#, i was able to read the macro file and get the recorded macro content. I just want to map the macro content with respective excel. since i done the excel operation on two different excels, i was not able to map the excel filename with each macro line correctly

Is it possible to get the filename from the macro file itself? Currently I am researching it, but I still can't find a solid solution. I need some solution in C# .NET.

Appreciate your response.

Comment: What? Can you be more specific and provide more details about relationship between VBA macro and C#?

Comment: "if my macro has stored 10 Excel functions in one file" - it's not clear what you mean by this.

Comment: @TimWilliams I have recorded a macro with few excel operations i performed in two different excel files . After that i saved the macro file (.xlsm). Through c#, i was able to read the macro file and get the recorded macro content. I just want to map the macro content with respective excel. since i done the excel operation on two different excels, i was not able to map the excel filename with each macro line correctly

Answer (score 0):

While the question is not clear, as a guess as what you're after:

- You can output the saved path of a workbook using the property directly e.g.

  ActiveWorkbook.Path

  (But you can use any workbook object e.g. ThisWorkbook.Path in the workbook that hosts the code. If it's via an add-in, you will want to store the active workbook in a variable and then use that)
- Similarly you can output a worksheet name e.g.

  ActiveSheet.Name

You can loop through all worksheets in a workbook using the worksheets collection, e.g.

```
Dim TempWs as Worksheet
For Each TempWs in ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    Debug.Print TempWs.Name
Next TempWs
```

The above is VBA. For C#, the syntax is similar (for a stored workbook variable TempWb):

```
foreach (Excel.Worksheet sheet in TempWb.Worksheets)
{
    etc
}
```

Comment: I have recorded a macro with few excel operations i performed in two different excel fileshttps://stackoverflow.com/users/6791681/jakeyg . After that i saved the macro file (.xlsm). Through c#, i was able to read the macro file and get the recorded macro content. I just want to map the macro content with respective excel. since i done the excel operation on two different excels, i was not able to map the excel filename with each macro line correctly

Comment: Apologies, not quite sure still what you're aiming to do. If you can upload the workbook and some screenshots with comments, that will help.